# When I click for the redirect link it is showing the content of index.php instead of single_assignment_page.php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

When I click on a link to redirect to 'single_assignment_page.php' it is not showing the content of this page but it is showing the content of 'index.php'. That's something I don't want but in the URL bar it is showing the right URL that I want. I'm working with my own theme in WordPress.

**front-page.php  with the link at the bottom**

```
<div class="container">
<h2 class="title-section" >Opdrachten</h2>
<p>Hieronder staan de opdrachten vermeld die zijn ingezonden door bedrijven en particulieren. Het is gesorteerd van nieuw naar oud. De opdrachten zijn alleen te zien voor ingelogde gebruikers.</p>

<?php
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, voornaam, achternaam, bedrijfsnaam, telefoonnummer, emailadres, titel_opdracht, opdrachtbeschrijving FROM form_entry"); // Query to fetch data from database table and storing in $results
if(!empty($results))                        // Checking if $results have some values or not
{
    echo "<table width='100%' border='0'>"; // Adding <table> and <tbody> tag outside foreach loop so that it wont create again and again
    echo "<tbody>";
    foreach($results as $row){
        echo "<tr>";                           // Adding rows of table inside foreach loop
        echo "<th>ID</th>" . "<td>" . $row->id . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<td colspan='2'><hr size='1'></td>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Voornaam</th>" . "<td>" . $row->voornaam . "</td>";   //fetching data from user_ip field
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<td colspan='2'><hr size='1'></td>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Achternaam</th>" . "<td>" . $row->achternaam . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<td colspan='2'><hr size='1'></td>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Bedrijfsnaam</th>" . "<td>" . $row->bedrijfsnaam . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<td colspan='2'><hr size='1'></td>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Telefoonnummer</th>" . "<td>" . $row->telefoonnummer . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<td colspan='2'><hr size='1'></td>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>E-mailadres</th>" . "<td>" . $row->emailadres . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<td colspan='2'><hr size='1'></td>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Titel opdracht</th>" . "<td>" . $row->titel_opdracht . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<td colspan='2'><hr size='1'></td>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Opdrachtbeschrijving</th>" . "<td>" . $row->opdrachtbeschrijving . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<td colspan='2'><hr size='1'></td>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td><a href="single_assignment_page.php?id='.$row->id.'">Hello</td>';
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";

}
?>
```

**single_assignment_page.php**

```
<?php $assignment_id = $_GET['id']; ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php the_content(); ?>
<p>Hey</p>
<p>Hey</p>
<p>Hey</p>
<p>Hey</p>
<p>Hey</p>
<p>Hey</p>
<p>Hey</p>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I already tried some things:

- Tried to redirect without the id at the end of the url, then he still shows the index.php content.
- Tried to redirect to a other PHP file, but it is still showing the content of index.php.
- Edit the .htaccess file but I still got the same problem.

I hope someone can help me out, because I've been stuck with this problem for a whole day. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Can you change your link from relative to absolute and see if it's working? For example `http://localhost/project/single_assignment_page.php?id=1`. Additionally try to visit this URL in browser

Comment: @rceman I just tried that, but it didn't help either. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Maybe there's some kind of URL rewriting involved. Did Wordpress or you create an .htaccess file with mod rewrite or the like for chance?

Comment: @shaedrich I did not create .htaccess by myself, so WordPress created it. This is the .htaccess file now:

 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: @Jakub Can you empty the .htaccess and save and check if it's working? If it does, put the content back in and we know, it has to do with the rewrite.

Comment: @shaedrich I just tried that and it is still not working.

Comment: There's probably some logic in the index.php handling an incoming parameter with the filename you tried to access and including that file in some way. Do you think, you can find that line?

Comment: @shaedrich I got the solution. I had to make the single_assignment_page.php as a page template then create a page and assign the template to that page. Then instead of linking to single_assignment_page.php, I had to link to the page's permalink. But at least thank you for trying to helping me out, I appreciate that very much.

Comment: @Jakub No problem. I'm glad, you found a solution.